# What are legal characters for an HTML element id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What characters can I use in an identifier for an HTML element?

For example:

`<SPAN id="section[5]" ...>`

(Or rather, should I stick to certain characters to make sure the `id` works across all major browsers/JavaScript engine).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In HTML5, the only restrictions are that the ID must be unique within the document, contain at least one character and contain no spaces. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-id-attribute

As other answers have pointed out, HTML 4 is more restrictive and specifies that

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 14):

In HTML 4, the [`id` attribute holds a NAME token](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) which are [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

As pointed out in a previous post, depending on your implementation you may have troubles with colons and periods along with others: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-is-a-valid-value-for-id-attributes-in-html)

Comment: In HTML5, there are fewer restrictions: the ID must be unique within the document, contain at least one character and contain no spaces, and that's it. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: As @Tim Down said, HTML5 gets rid of most of these restrictions. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class, which also explains how to escape weird IDs (or other attribute values) for use in CSS and JavaScript. ([I’ve also made a tool for that.](http://mothereffingcssescapes.com/))

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

Comment: HTML5 gets rid of most of these restrictions. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class, which also explains how to escape weird IDs (or other attribute values) for use in CSS and JavaScript. ([I’ve also made a tool for that.](http://mothereffingcssescapes.com/))

Answer (score 3):

All the above answers + **ID** must be **unique**

Answer (score 2):

From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html):

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: HTML5 gets rid of most of these restrictions. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class, which also explains how to escape weird IDs (or other attribute values) for use in CSS and JavaScript. ([I’ve also made a tool for that.](http://mothereffingcssescapes.com/))

Answer (score 0):

actually I can successfully use a ° too for example

< span id= "test°" />

Seems to be allowed, and I have no problem with jQuery or other ways to fetch dom elements via the selectors.
Perhaps other chars work, but I didn't test them all.